# Pass SF security review and keep <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/> in a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, security-review

to pass security review we must avoid <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
But without the escape="false", my message will not be clickable anymore.
So inside my controller, I try to encode directly the message like this :

```
String urlEncodedTimestamp = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(myLink, 'UTF-8');
ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message( ApexPages.Severity.CONFIRM, myLink)
```

Do you think it's enough and secure to pass the SR ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to pass a Security Review with `escape="false"`. If the scanner flags your code, and you're absolutely certain that it's impossible to perform XSS, CRSF, or other types of injection, you can argue your case with the Security Review Team. Just make sure that your code is actually secure, and they'll allow it.